# Is there any way to use chisel to generate blackbox from verilog text content? (define val based on text content in scala)

Tags: scala, chisel

I'm working with a team that use verilog as well.
I feel it is way faster to use chisel power to manage the interconnections between modules than bare verilog.
I can see from the chisel tutorial that blackbox wrappers are written manually.The io signals are defined by hand.

Is it possible to extract the io info from verilog and define chisel blackbox io automatically? (aka, generate a blackbox from verilog instead of defining a blackbox class by some human being by reading the verilog. )

for example:

```scala
val bbox = blackbox("someModule.v")
```

and then, the bbox will be an functioning blackbox with all the ios and name defined.

Since the io signal is `val`s in scala, I wonder if there is a meta way towards this goal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is! Check out `HasBlackBoxInline`:

https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/blackboxes.html#blackboxes-with-in-line-verilog

```scala
class BlackBoxRealAdd extends BlackBox with HasBlackBoxInline {
  val io = IO(new Bundle() {
    val in1 = Input(UInt(64.W))
    val in2 = Input(UInt(64.W))
    val out = Output(UInt(64.W))
  })
  setInline("BlackBoxRealAdd.v",
    s"""
      |module BlackBoxRealAdd(
      |    input  [15:0] in1,
      |    input  [15:0] in2,
      |    output [15:0] out
      |);
      |always @* begin
      |  out <= $realtobits($bitstoreal(in1) + $bitstoreal(in2));
      |end
      |endmodule
    """.stripMargin)
}
```

By default this BlackBox will be emitted to the output directory with its given name.

Comment: Hi, this is not the what I meant, what I mean is, without defining the `val in1, val in2...` in IO , we might can use a method to scan the verilog content and define the chisel io signals automatically (thus the module name and io signals does not need to be defined by a human)

Comment: I see. That's certainly possible but you would need a Verilog parser to do it. Full Verilog parsing is a difficult thing to do (see https://symbiflow.github.io/sv-tests/) but one sufficient to grab the ports of well-formed Verilog should be pretty easy. The main issue you'll run into is driving the interface in Chisel since Scala is strongly typed, you can't use a Bundle (unless you want to generate code) so the natural approach would be to populate a https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/latest/chisel3/Record.html which is somewhat of a power-user API.

Comment: I see. Seems generating scala code should be an easier way.